# Why do I see a numeral in brackets in the Title bar?

Tags: support

I often see a number in brackets in the Title bar when GIS.se is open for a long time. What does it stand for?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means since you viewed that page there is 1 (or 2,3,4) new additional questions been added to GIS Stack Exchange - click the questions tab and it will refresh the page and the number will go until another new question is posted.